# How to call controller action from d3.js or any javascript in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I am trying to understand how I can call a controller action when a user presses a circle in my d3.js graph. The idea is that the controller action should show more information about that circle from a database but really what I'm interested in is how to call any rails controller action from a user's click. I haven't put the controller code in because I'm really just interested in how the call is made.

The relevant part of my javascript looks like:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.group * 3; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag)
      .on('click', connectedNodes)
      .on("dblclick",getprofile(d));


      function getprofile(d){
      $.ajax({
        url: "/users/show" ,
        type: "GET",
        data : { name: JSON.stringify(d.name) }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the `dblclick` like this:

```
.on("dblclick", getprofile);
```